# JSON data return, pulling a column in a loop

Tags: json, google-maps-api-3

```
var query = 'SELECT GRIDCODE, geometry FROM ' +
'1gTfoIdxkj0MkGMJ1zGSaa__BsYSrgMovo1fbuDo';
```

This query in the Google API is returning me data that I am mapping. I am looking to grab them in a loop. I have the following

```
    var rows = data['rows'];
    for (var i in rows) {
        var newCoordinates = [];
        var newCoordinates = constructNewCoordinates(rows[i][1]['geometry']);
        var whichNode="";
        var whichNode = rows[i][0]['GRIDCODE'];
        etc...
```

The script works great breaking out the geocodes in the geometry incoming data but I can't seem to simply grab the GRIDCODE number that comes with each row. Am I misunderstanding the syntax in the new coordinates in that I am grabbing the first column called geometry in row i. So if I wanted to know the GRIDCODE I would be pulling the 0 column in row i called GRIDCODE? Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated this example:

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_FusionTables_generic_JSON_linkto.html?lat=39.923549&lng=-86.306907&zoom=10&type=m&tableid=1im8RszWUjZZhZdBnO8C0rfWGvT059O2EKk6TvZs&tablequery=SELECT%20%20geometry,%20GRID_CODE%20FROM

To put the "GRIDCODE" in the infowindow.  If you read the code you can see how I access it.  Note that I changed the order of GRIDCODE and geometry in the query (my code assumes geometry is first, the next two columns, if they exist, are put in the infowindow)

Comment: geocodezip. Wonderful. The code was a bit much for my expertise but i was able to tease out the ability to grab that variable. I do have a question about the overlay but I will play with it and be and might be back to you. You make wonderful examples! Thanks again. Certainly worth the points!